# Python, Passing --junitxml to pytest.main()

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I am calling my tests as `pytest.main(["--junitxml" , args.resultXml, "--someargument", path])`.
This is my conftest.py:

```
   parser.addoption(
      '--someargument',
      dest="someArgument",
      help="Path to someargument")
   parser.addoption(
      '--junitxml',
      action="store",
      dest="resultXml",
      default = "resultXML.xml",
      help="Path to XML file")
```

However I am getting this error:

```
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --junitxml/--junit-xml: conflicting option string(s): --junitxml
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to add an already existing option (`--junitxml`). Either you want to use the built-in option - then you can't add the option again with different parameters, or you want to add your own option with different functionality - in this case you have to give it an unused name.

Comment: I want to use the already existing option. I want my pytest.main() call to be supplied with --junitxml argument so that the test can dump the result xml which can be then used by jenkins. The other way of doing this is: ```py.test sample_tests.py --junitxml=C:\path\to\out_report.xml``` but I am looking through pytest.main()

Comment: In this case just remove the second `addoption` - you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen removing addOption worked